# CosmosDB : How to apply concurrency while inserting a document (in parallel requests)

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

**Background:**

We have a EventHub where thousands of events are logged every day. The Azure function are configured on trigger over this eventhub on arrival of new messages. The azure function does following two tasks:

1. `Write` the raw message into document DB (collection 1)
2. `Upsert` an  summary (aggregated) message into collection 2 of document Db. Before writing a message it checks if a summary message is already exists based on `partition key` and `unique id` (not id), it a doc exists then it update the doc with new aggregated value and if not then insert a new doc. This unique id is created based on a business logic.

**Problem Statement:**

More than one summary document is getting created for a PartitionKey and unique Id

**Scenario Details**

- let us say, for PartitionKey `PartitionKey1`  there is no summary
  document created in  Collection for computed `unique key`.
- multiple messages (suppose 2) arrived at eventhub and which have triggered azure functions.
- all these 2 requests run concurrently, Since no existing document is found using the query, so each request make a message, now the Upsert function is
  invoked almost at the same time for writing summary document by concurrent request and resulted to have multiple summary documents for a PartitionKey and unique Id.

I've searched and read about `Optimistic Concurrency` which definitely I will implement for update scenario. but I could not able to find any way through which `insert` scenarios can be handled?

Comment: Unique key and row key both are scoped to a partition. Looks like a stream processor ASA (Azure stream Analytics) or Spark may help you in this situation.  check screen cast on ASA https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SD6QQ6nmpq8&t=173s  for spark https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P9Qz4pwKm_0&t=1010s

Comment: Thanks Rafat. Let me check those. One of my collegeue also mentioned to use Redis cache distributed lock to achieve it. Do you think, I should explore that too?

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I suggest you use Stored Procedure to achieve this.

Cosmos DB to guarantee ACID for all operations that are part of a single stored procedure.

As the official said: If the collection the stored procedure is registered against is a single-partition collection, then the transaction is scoped to all the documents within the collection. If the collection is partitioned, then stored procedures are executed in the transaction scope of a single partition key. Each stored procedure execution must then include a partition key value corresponding to the scope the transaction must run under.

For more information about Stored Procedure of Cosmos DB and how to create Stored Procedure, we can refer to:

[Azure Cosmos DB server-side programming: Stored procedures, database triggers, and UDFs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming)

[Create and use stored procedures using C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming#client-sdk-support)

Comment: Thanks Lee, let me check the stored procedure approach.

Comment: @user1672994 I am checking to see how things are going there on this issue.